# vectorized addition in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

How do I vectorize addition between columns in a numpy array?  For example, what is the fastest way to implement something like:

```
import numpy

ary = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6,7],[7,8,9],[9,10,11]])
for i in range(ary.shape[0]):
    ary[i,0] += ary[i,1]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum elements in a row (Python/Numpy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30387280/sum-elements-in-a-row-python-numpy)

Comment: Linking a similar question with a dissimilar answer is not helpful

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem -- you asked how to get the rowwise sum of a numpy array. The link above shows you how to do that (sure, it may not answer your _exact_ question, but it does answer the question you seem to be asking). If you were actually asking a _different_ question, please clarify. Are you asking how to add _only_ the first two columns?

Comment: The slicing operator in RomanPerekhrest's answer is not in the linked question.  I realize ary.sum works for only 2 columns like my original example, I revised my question to include an additional column.

Comment: Ah, then the duplicate for this question is [How to add two columns of a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735608/how-to-add-two-columns-of-a-numpy-array).

Answer (score 2):

With [`numpy.ndarray.sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sum.html) over axis `1`:

```
ary[:,0] = ary.sum(axis=1)
```

Or the same with straightforward addition on slices:

```
ary[:,0] = ary[:, 0] + ary[:, 1]
```

Comment: Does something speak against `ary[:, 0] += ary[:, 1]`?

Comment: The slicing operator is the syntax I was looking for, however I am curious if ary.sum is faster, and if it can be used to add the 1st and 2nd column in cases where there are more than 2 columns and I don't want the 3rd and subsequent columns included in the sum.

Comment: @Brad `sum(axis=1)` is applied over the _entire_ array, so if you only want to sum two columns you could slice those columns first e.g. `ary[:, :2].sum(axis=1)` will select only the first two columns, and then apply `sum(axis=1)` to that slice